# border-bottom is not showing for absolute columns

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

I have a scrollable table (overflow:auto) with first column and last column position:absolute.

and the remaining columns are scrollable.

The problem is on certain action I am giving border-bottom to all tds in a tr. 
Border is not visible in Chrome and Safari for the first & last columns which are position:absolute columns. It is visible fine for the rest of the columns.

It is visible for all the columns in firefox.
can somebody advise how to fix this?

```
tr.chromeAvgLinerDesc td{
    border-bottom: 3px solid @sortIndicatorClr;//Descending
}
```

Comment: shall you show your `scrollable table`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try by adding `border-collapse: collapse;` this might solve the problem.

```
table{
border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..however no change.. border is still not showing for those columns.